# Need to merge 2 rows in dynamic table

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0

Hi I have created dynamic table as below and in that I have 2 rows with same id 
How should I merge them.

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt = (DataTable)Session["AddtoCart"];
DataRow dr1 = dt.NewRow();
foreach (var key in collection.AllKeys)
{
    dr1["Description"] = collection["hdDescription"];
    dr1["Title"] = collection["hdTitle"];
    dr1["ActualQuantity"] = collection["hdactualquantity"];
    dr1["PropertyId"] = collection["hdPropertyId"];
    dr1["Quantity"] = collection["Quantity"];
    TempData["AddedtoCart"] = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AddtoCart"].ToString();
}
dt.Rows.Add(dr1);
```

My added rows are as

```
Propertyid, Quantity, ActualQuantity
1             5          10
1             2          10
2             3          20
2             4          20
```

Th result i needed is as

```
Propertyid, Quantity, ActualQuantity
1             7          10
2             7          20
```

---

**Update**: i have tried [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46345032/284240):

```
var query = dt.AsEnumerable()
    .GroupBy(row => row.Field<int>("PropertyId"))// issue over this line
    .Select(grp => new
    {
        PropertyId = grp.Key,
        Quantity = grp.Sum(row => row.Field<int>("Quantity")),
        ActualQuantity = grp.First().Field<int>("ActualQuantity"),
        Title = grp.First().Field<int>("Title"),
        Description = grp.First().Field<int>("Description")
    });

var SumByIdTable = dt.Clone();
foreach (var x in query)
    SumByIdTable.Rows.Add(x.PropertyId, x.Quantity, x.ActualQuantity,x.Title, x.Description);

Session["AddtoCart"] = SumByIdTable;
```

but I am getting issue as Specified cast is not valid. on  .GroupBy(row => row.Field("PropertyId"))

**Update 2**: I have tried below code but i am getting issue

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.Columns.Add("PropertyId", typeof(int));
dt.Columns.Add("Quantity", typeof(int));
dt.Columns.Add("Description", Type.GetType("System.String"));
dt.Columns.Add("Title", Type.GetType("System.String"));
dt.Columns.Add("ActualQuantity", typeof(int));
DataRow dr1 = dt.NewRow();
foreach (var key in collection.AllKeys)
{
    dr1["Description"] = collection["hdDescription"];
    dr1["Title"] = collection["hdTitle"];
    dr1["ActualQuantity"] = Convert.ToInt32(collection["hdactualquantity"]);
    dr1["PropertyId"] = Convert.ToInt32(collection["hdPropertyId"]);
    dr1["Quantity"] = Convert.ToInt32(collection["Quantity"]);
    TempData["AddedtoCart"] = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AddtoCart"].ToString();
}
dt.Rows.Add(dr1);

var query = dt.AsEnumerable()
    .GroupBy(row => row.Field<int>("PropertyId"))
    .Select(grp => new
    {
        PropertyId = grp.Key,
        Quantity = grp.Sum(row => row.Field<int>("Quantity")),
        ActualQuantity = grp.First().Field<int>("ActualQuantity"),
        Title = grp.First().Field<string>("Title"),
        Description = grp.First().Field<string>("Description")
    });

var SumByIdTable = dt.Clone();
foreach (var x in query)
    SumByIdTable.Rows.Add(x.PropertyId, x.Quantity, x.ActualQuantity,x.Title, x.Description);

Session["AddtoCart"] = SumByIdTable;
```

but I am getting issue in

`SumByIdTable.Rows.Add(x.PropertyId, x.Quantity, x.ActualQuantity,x.Title, x.Description);`

> Input string was not in a correct format.

**Resolved Update 3**: I have tried below code and is working

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.Columns.Add("PropertyId", typeof(int));
dt.Columns.Add("Quantity", typeof(int));
dt.Columns.Add("Description", Type.GetType("System.String"));
dt.Columns.Add("Title", Type.GetType("System.String"));
dt.Columns.Add("ActualQuantity", typeof(int));
DataRow dr1 = dt.NewRow();
foreach (var key in collection.AllKeys)
{
    dr1["Description"] = collection["hdDescription"];
    dr1["Title"] = collection["hdTitle"];
    dr1["ActualQuantity"] = Convert.ToInt32(collection["hdactualquantity"]);
    dr1["PropertyId"] = Convert.ToInt32(collection["hdPropertyId"]);
    dr1["Quantity"] = Convert.ToInt32(collection["Quantity"]);
    TempData["AddedtoCart"] = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AddtoCart"].ToString();
}
dt.Rows.Add(dr1);

var query = dt.AsEnumerable()
    .GroupBy(row => row.Field<int>("PropertyId"))
    .Select(grp => new
    {
        PropertyId = grp.Key,
        Quantity = grp.Sum(row => row.Field<int>("Quantity")),
        ActualQuantity = grp.First().Field<int>("ActualQuantity"),
        Title = grp.First().Field<string>("Title"),
        Description = grp.First().Field<string>("Description")
    });

var SumByIdTable = dt.Clone();
foreach (var x in query)
    SumByIdTable.Rows.Add(Convert.ToInt32(x.PropertyId), Convert.ToInt32(x.Quantity), x.Description, x.Title, Convert.ToInt32(x.ActualQuantity));

Session["AddtoCart"] = SumByIdTable;
```

changes was I have to add the value in SumByIdTable as clone set in dt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use LINQ (-to-DataTable):

```
var query = dt.AsEnumerable()
    .GroupBy(row => row.Field<int>("Propertyid"))
    .Select(grp => new { 
        Propertyid     = grp.Key,
        Quantity       = grp.Sum(row => row.Field<int>("Quantity")),
        ActualQuantity = grp.First().Field<int>("ActualQuantity")       
    });

var SumByIdTable = dt.Clone();
foreach(var x in query)
    SumByIdTable.Rows.Add(x.Propertyid, x.Quantity, x.ActualQuantity);
```

Comment: Finally I need to add that table in Session["AddtoCart"] = dt; so in that case i need to add as Session["AddtoCart"] = SumByIdTable; correct

Comment: Yes, or asssign it to the other variable: dt = SumByIdTable;

Comment: If the properties are not ints but strings change it accordingly at row.Field<string>

Comment: so u mean i have to add column as  dt.Columns.Add("PropertyId", Type.GetType("System.Int"));  ?

Comment: @Xtremcool: no, i mean you should look what `collection["hdPropertyId"]` returns. I dont know the datasource of your table.

Comment: please review updated question, I am getting issue at last statement SumByIdTable.Rows.Add(x.PropertyId, x.Quantity, x.ActualQuantity,x.Title, x.Description);

Comment: Now working I just need to set value added in SumByIdTable.Rows.Add on baiss of dt.clone